# Collection view scroll with limited cells

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with only 1 cell to start with the user can add more cells as they please. The collection view does not scroll until I have enough cells to go past the scrollview frame.

How can I allow the collection view to scroll up and down without having more cells?

This behavior is similar to an empty table view. You can still scroll up and down just a bit.

I have been searching but cannot find a way to solve this, and honestly it is a weird question to ask I guess.

Any help is great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection views and table views are both subclasses of UIScrollView. The behaviour you are looking for is part of the scroll view - controlled by the `bounces` and `alwaysBounceVertical` properties.

[Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/alwaysBounceVertical).

Comment: I cant believe I missed this! I need to better my skill for reading documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It has helped a lot